# Why does Visual Studio 2019 deletes my referenced assemblies after the build?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I have a Visual Studio 2019 solution that I inherited from someone else with multiple projects.
I'm trying to build one of the projects in particular.
I have a reference to an external assembly with "copy local" set to true.

When I build my project, my referenced assembly gets copied over tot he output folder but then it gets deleted.

I know it gets copied because I have tried using the post build event "dir $(TargetDir)" and it shows the dll.

Any idea why it would get deleted afterward?

Comment: You can try to diagnose problem by inspecting build logs. [Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-view-save-and-configure-build-log-files?view=vs-2019#use-binary-logs-to-make-it-easier-to-browse-large-log-files)

Comment: @JL0PD  Indeed. Thee is a tool named Fody reference in the project file. It deletes the dll in the target directory.

Comment: Fody uses IL-weaving to rewrite your  dlls. Check `FodyWeavers.xml`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was caused by by these lines in my csproj file:

```
<Target AfterTargets="AfterBuild;NonWinFodyTarget" Name="CleanReferenceCopyLocalPaths">
    <Delete Files="@(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths->'$(OutDir)%(DestinationSubDirectory)%(Filename)%(Extension)')" />
  </Target>
```

The solution was using Fody to weave the assemblies.
I had removed the weaving, but this line in the csproj file was a left over from the use of Fody.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you have used some nuget packages like `Costura.Fody` which could merge your specific external assembly into the main output file while it is set to **Copy Local True**.

**So** please check if your `FodyWeavers.xml` file has [any merge operation](https://github.com/Fody/Costura) of your external assembly.

In my side, I have an external assembly called `ClassLibrary22.dll` and set it to **CopyLocal** to `true`.

[image]

And add these on `FodyWeavers.xml` file:

[image]

So the assembly `ClassLibrary22.dll` will be merged into the main project `exe` or `dll` output file and did not exist under output folder.
That is the cause.